# Multiple APKs in Release

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk, wear-os

## Context

I've recently closed in on the release phase of a pet project application that uses both Android Wear and the mobile. I've uploaded it as an Alpha release to the Play Developer Console, and the Wear portion was approved as well, but when viewing the store listing, the compatibility overview shows up as if only the mobile APK was being offered.

I've tried to make it recognize both versions by following a few tips here:

- Make sure the `<uses-permission>` elements are identical in both
- Configure Gradle for signing with the same key (even though I used Android Studio's "Generate Signed APKs" option)
- Split the APKs by commenting out the `wearApp` declaration in the Gradlefile

The developer docs say that I need to enable "Advanced mode" on the "APK Files page", but since the Console has transitioned to Release Manager, I don't think that's an option any more, and it keeps accepting only one APK, either the phone or the wear, but not both.
During testing, naturally, the Wear device could run the APK without any issues, both in debug as well as instant run mode, even from the menu (no ADB connection required).

## Questions

- Why is the Play Store only showing only the mobile as compatible when a "combined" APK (Android Studio, by default, embeds the Wear APK into the mobile APK, which *should* not cause an issue with Android Wear 2.0 either) is uploaded
- How can I attach two APKs to a release, alpha or not, so that both show up in the listing?
- How do I need to package the APK from Studio to achieve the same, if needed?

## Reference files

### `wear.build`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25

    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tech.provingground.divemonitor"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.0-remote"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("[path/to/file]")
            storePassword "[redacted]"
            keyAlias "mobile keystore"
            keyPassword "[redacted]"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile project(':commons')
}
```

### `mobile.build`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tech.provingground.divemonitor"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.0-local"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("[path/to/file]")
            storePassword "[redacted]"
            keyAlias "mobile keystore"
            keyPassword "[redacted]"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    wearApp project(':wear')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    compile project(':commons')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0.pr2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-csv
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.9.0.pr2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `versionCode` attributes of the two APKs differ. Only then will they coexist.